# Реализация template в .cpp-файле

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Всех приветствую. Недавно начал свой путь познаний C++.

Честно говоря, темы такой мной не было найдено, по этой причине создаю новую.

К примеру, есть такой хэдер-класс:

```
People.h

class People{
  public:

   void SomeMethod();

   template<class T>

   T ReadPeopleInfo(T& data, T& yet_data);    
};
```

Как можно реализовать ReadPeopleInfo в cpp файле?

Пробовал так:

```
People.cpp

T People::ReadPeopleInfo(T& data, T& yet_data){


}
```

выдает ошибку

> Ошибка E0795 для специализации шаблон функции "People::ReadPeopleInfo"
>   требуется синтаксис "template<>"

Как быть?

P.S В дальнейшем нужно будет сделать single-pattern, по этому template нужно запихать в class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да как и объявляли:

```
template<class T>
T People::ReadPeopleInfo(T& data, T& yet_data)
{
    ....
}
```

Только вот после этого у вас сразу будет вопрос - почему линковщик говорит, что не видит `People::ReadPeopleInfo`?

Определения шаблонных сущностей должны располагаться в заголовочных файлах. Скомпилировать отдельно, в отдельном файле так, чтоб ими можно было воспользоваться из другого файла - можно, но сложно и надо знать заранее, для каких именно типов.

Так что возвращайте определение назад в заголовочный файл.

Comment: Просьба к минусующим - я не против, но объясняйте, что не так - ведь на ошибках я должен учиться, не лишайте такой возможности :)